# jQuery text Node Object to string

Tags: javascript, jquery, text

I'm using this code:

```
/**
 * Get Text Nodes from an Element
 * Returns and object unless number is passed in
 * Numbers is 0 based
 */
(function( $ ) {
$.fn.textNodes = function(number) {
    var nodes = jQuery(this).contents().filter(function(){
        return this.nodeType == 3;
    });
    if(jQuery.isNumber(number)){
        return nodes[number];
    }
    return nodes;
};
})( jQuery );
```

It's used to grab the text nodes out of html

For example:

```
<div>
    <span>Testing</span>
    What is this?
</div>
```

I'm looking for `What is this?`

This works, as I can do a console.log and see the result in the console.

But when I try and use the result in an input field it give me: `[object Text]`

How can I use the result as a string value?

I've tried toString() but that gives the same result, unless I missed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works, but it doesn't employ the beauty of jQuery. How about:

```
(function($) {
    $.expr[':'].textnode = function(element) {
        return element.nodeType == 3;
    }

    $.valHooks["#text"] = { get: function(elem) {
        return $.trim(elem.nodeValue);
    }}

})(jQuery)
```

use it this way:

```
lastText = $("div").contents(":textnode:last").val()
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YXjEB/

Answer (score 5):

Use the [nodeValue](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Node.nodeValue) property:

```
$("#yourInputField").val(yourTextNode.nodeValue);
```

Comment: This is the correct answer to my question.  I liked the spin thg435 gave.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You receive the text node as a DOM-object which is correct behaviour, when you need the actual text use: `textContent` or `nodeValue`.

See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sJuJJ/1/).

Comment: `textContent` is not implemented in older browsers, including IE < 9. Stick with `nodeValue` or `data`, both of which are available in all major browsers.